# Check for carriage return\line feed in tab delimited text file in C#

Tags: c#

I have what I believed to be new line feed\carriage return in tab delimited file that I am reading using C# Stream Reader, please see an extract below, the second and third lines is actually a single line that contains what I believed to be carriage return after "NL" on the second line. I have tried using the code below to determine the presence of new line\carriage return, but no luck.

Could someone please help?

*Code extract*

```
 string line = sr.ReadLine();
 if (line.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
 {
    MessageBox.Show("New line detected");
 }
```

*File extract*

```
1224    TX68176 FR123   0.2241  2788848 JP31650 B62G7K6 J7618E108   8630
----------
1225    TX68176 NL
----------
128 0.2241  2788848 JP3165000   B62G7K6 J7618E108   8630
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154170/discussion-on-question-by-obotor-check-for-carriage-return-line-feed-in-tab-deli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are reading the line with ReadLine, you will never get an `Environment.NewLine` at the end of the line.  Your real problem is that you have a line of data, which you are probably expecting to be a single line, split into multiple lines.  The exception you are getting does not come from having an newline in the line you read, and you are not going to fix it by trying to detect a newline character.

The problem probably comes from the rest of your code expecting fields in the line that are not there, because this part of the code read a line of text data that was only a partial line of data.  The rest of your code chokes on not getting all the fields in that data line.  To detect that you have only a partial line of data, you will need to probably detect on line length, since it seems to be a fixed length formatted file, or detect on the number of fields after you split it with tabs.

Comment: @Agapwlesu, Thank you, your solution resolved the issue

Comment: Thanks everyone for your contributions